# "Desired Capabilities must be a dictionary" error when passing dict into parametrized method

Tags: python, automated-tests, appium, pytest, python-appium

I'm testing mobile applications using Appium and pytest. Following error appears when I'm trying to pass a list of dictionaries through the parametrized pytest mark.

```
 WebDriverException: Message: Desired Capabilities must be a dictionary
```

It works fine when I'm not using `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` and pass desired capabilities directly as a dictionary to `webdriver.Remote`.

I've simplified my code a little bit for better understanding:

```
class TestQATestProject(object): 
  def get_all(self):
      return [
          {'platformName': 'Android'},
          {'platformName': 'Android'}
      ]


  @pytest.mark.parametrize('desired_caps', get_all())
  def setup_method(self, desired_caps):
      self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', 
  desired_caps)
      self.driver.implicitly_wait(5000)
```

**[UPD]** I've figured out that `@pytest.mark.parametrize` doesn't work properly for `setup_method`. So is there another way to run tests on different configs?

Comment: I don't think there's a self, because the decorator is outside any method

Comment: ok, my bad, lets say there will be some kinda devices.get.all(). its not a point

Comment: would it work to just `print(desired_caps)` and compare it to what you expect instead of the `webdriver` code? Because I'm not convinced that your code as it is now would work: `get_all` is still an instance method of `TestQATestProject`.

Comment: marks in @pytest.mark.parameterize is deperecated since pytest 4.0 which might be causing the issue. Please go through the given url if you are using latest pytest:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html

Comment: thanks a lot. problem is solved with @pytest.mark.unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@pytest.mark.unit` makes a deal for me